# why does socket emit work but not io.in emit?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm working on a chat app. The client sends the `chatId` to the server and the server joins the room and sends current messages back to the client. When the user sends a new message, it should be saved and emitted to the group. Everything works as expected except emitting the messages to the group. If I comment the `io.in emit` and uncomment the `socket.emit` then, as expected, the connected socket gets the message. Why doesn't the group emit work? Is it ok for socket to be in multiple groups?

```
socket.on('joinChat', async (chatId) => {
    try {
      const chat = await Chat.findById(chatId).populate({
        path: 'messages',
        populate: {path: 'author'}
      }).limit(50);
      if (chat) {
        socket.join(chat._id);
        socket.emit('allMessages', chat.messages);
      };
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    };
  });

socket.on('submitNewMessage', async (data) => {
    try {
      let message = await Message.create({
        content: data.content,
    author: socket.user._id
      });
      if (message) {
        let chat = await Chat.findById(data.chatId);
        chat.messages.push(message._id);
    await chat.save();
    console.log('sending message to chat channel', chat._id);
    io.in(chat._id).emit('newMessage', message);
    // socket.emit('newMessage', message)
      };
    } catch(err) {};
  });
```

React client

```
export default function ChatPage(props) {
  
  const {socket} = useSelector((state) => state.socket);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [chatId, setChatId] = useState(null);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  const classes = useStyles();

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (socket && chatId) {
      socket.emit('submitNewMessage', ({content: message, chatId: chatId}));
      setMessage('');
    };
  };

  useEffect(async () => {
    let res = await api.getChatId({friendId: props.match.params.userId});
    if (res.status === 200 && res.data.chatId) {
      setChatId(res.data.chatId);
      setUserId(res.data.userId);
    };
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chatId && socket) {
      socket.emit('joinChat', chatId);
      socket.on('allMessages', (allMessages) => {
        setMessages([...allMessages]);
      });
      socket.on('newMessage', (newMessage) => {
        console.log('received message!');
        setMessages((prev) => [...prev, newMessage])
      });
    };
  }, [chatId, socket]);

  return (
    ...
  )
```

Comment: The obvious question is whether `chat._id` is actually the same in both message handlers as that could explain why `io.in(chat._id).emit()` doesn't reach the socket you want it to.

Comment: Yes that was my first assumption, i console log them out they matched. I tried to String them just in case, same outcome. I then hardcode them to 'one', same outcome -__-

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're logging the same socket each time you check `chat._id`?  If you are using a `<form>` in the client to trigger any of these messages, it's possible the client page is reloading and causing a new socket connection to replace the old one and the new one isn't in the room.  I've seen that problem before.  Add a log of `socket.id` along with `chat._id` in each message handler to make sure they match.

Comment: Could it be from not closing the socket properly? I just realized I haven't been cleaning up. I'm going to do it now and hope it fixes the issue.

Comment: When you leave a web page, you don't have to close the  socket, the browser will do that for you.  So, not sure what you mean by "closing the socket".  Did you log the `socket.id` to see if it was the same?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using react and the socket is connected in the `app.js`  and since i only want the users to receive messages when their on the specified chat page, i have to leave the channel when user leaves the page. 
I implement this but still didnt fix it.

Comment: I see the channel listed here `Map {
  '60e715eae708fa17fcdb5e39' => Set { 'J_gKUQlyu6vUC0ZyAAAN' },
  'J_gKUQlyu6vUC0ZyAAAN' => Set { 'J_gKUQlyu6vUC0ZyAAAN' },
  '60ef97873c1d3da51fdf14c7' => Set { 'J_gKUQlyu6vUC0ZyAAAN' } }` i console logged `io.of("/").adapter.rooms`

Comment: I can't really help further without being able to debug it myself and this isn't something we can run ourselves.

Comment: I think your right about the room id. I'm seeing new message arrive to all connected clients except the user who sent. I'll figure it out in the morning. Thanks for your help!